# Hashset Containg duplicate values ; Also ArrayList indexOf(string_present_in_list) returning -1

Tags: java, arraylist, contains, hashset, indexof

I have made a Hashset of StringBuilder.

The below code returns "true" even if that StringBuilder is present in Hashset:

```
if(!contains(sb_obj))
{
...
}
```

Also I have made a ArrayList of StringBuilder.

The below code returns "-1" even if ArrayList contains obj:

```
if(arr.indexOf(obj)==-1)
{
....
}
```

Why such behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are comparing different `StringBuilder` objects that have the same `String` values.

`StringBuilder` doesn't override `equals` and `hashCode` methods. This causes `HashSet` and `ArrayList` to use `Object`'s implementation of them which compares by identity. Since you are comparing different objects they are different.

Comment: I understood that but can you elaborate a little on how to write the override equals method.

Comment: Yes your assumption is exactly correct. Thats what happening. Please help

Comment: @ttripdee why do you need to use `StringBuilder`? Can't you  use `String`? It's a final class you can't extend it and override equals and hashCode.

Comment: 100s of Upvotes Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Please use String instead of storing StringBuilder object or if you want to store custom object override hashcode and equals methods whenever you are trying to add  and search back that object.

Please read the concept of hascode and equals method, you can find many examples over internet.